# How to remove database name on JOIN clauses when creating views?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a problem on one of my views. The current scenario is, there is one database template with a view. And the system copies the database template to a new database as a new "workspace" in the system.

The view inside the database includes the database name on the JOIN clauses like this:

```
LEFT JOIN `db_template`.`temp_table` `t1`
```

Even when I tried to recreate the view removing the database names, after executing I checked and the database names are automatically generated and are still there.

So, my problem is, when the db_template is copied, the database name inside the view is copied along the new "workspace" database, so it still references the db_template on the JOINs.

Is there a way to remove the database names when joining tables? I tried executing the create view from SQLyog if it helps.
I also tried saving the script into an .sql file and executing the file on a shell script using mysql command but the DB names are still there.

P.S.: I'm also using MySQL v5.5 if it helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the database where this view is created in is (1) default database for (a) current user (b) user who is set as definer (2) current database during creation?

Comment: yes it is the current database selected during creation.
and the definer of the view is set for another user (superuser)

Comment: I reproduce. If current database = view database != table database then I see database alias in view definition. Test all combinations, find those which do not add database alias, use one of them.